# cin.get gets one extra character?

Tags: c++, io, cin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

I was reading a group of characters via cin.get() and I noticed that my cin.get() was getting an exra character at the end of the input. Might anyone know how to fix this? Here's my code:

```
unsigned char c;

while(!cin.eof())
{
   c = cin.get();
   cout << (int)c << endl;
}
```

My issue is that the character it gets is one of 255 ascii value. I simply don't want it to get this extra character, but if the user enters in a ascii value of 255 without it being a garbage character at the end, then that should be fine. An example would be so for my output:

if I entered in abc\n in my output:

I get 
97
98
99
10
255

but I want:
97
98
99
10

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Why `!cin.eof()`? Is the input from a file.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Never use `cin.eof()` as a loop condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong). It almost always produces buggy code, as it has here.

Instead, try:

```
int c;
while ( (c=cin.get()) != EOF ) {
  cout << c << endl;
}
```

Or:

```
char c;
while (cin.get(c)) {
  cout << (int)c << endl;
}
```

Comment: Although you should probably not use `EOF` since the trait may return another value on end of file than `-1`, right?

Comment: @AlexisWilke - Perhaps generally, but not specifically for `cin`. `std::cin` will always use `std::char_traits<char>`, which uses `EOF`.

Answer (score 3):

The [`get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) function with no arguments returns an `int_type`, not a `char`. At the end of the stream, it returns a special *non-character* value that indicates end of file (usually -1). By assigning the result of `cin.get()` directly to an `unsigned char`, you are inadvertently throwing away this eof information. The relevant documentation quote is:

> 1) reads one character and returns it if available. Otherwise, returns `Traits::eof()` and sets `failbit` and `eofbit`.